# Is there a way to add a badge to an application icon in Android?

Tags: android, icons, badge

On the iPhone, you can add a numbered badge to the application icon. On BlackBerry, I've successfully painted an image onto the application's icon while in the program. I want to do this for Android as well. I don't want to use the notification bar, as it's not something that needs to be notified instantly. Instead, I just want the user to be able to see how many new messages are in the application just by looking at the application icon.

Comment: This is the best solution I have ever found. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24804467/957954

Comment: My Samsung note 5 shows them for Skype, Whatsapp and Facebook. So it must be possible.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Unfortunately, Android does not allow changing of the application icon because it's sealed in the APK once the program is compiled. There is no way to programmatically change it to a 'drawable'.

You may achieve your goal by using a widget instead of an icon. Widgets are highly customisable and can do what you want.

There's a short discussion about the difference between iPhone icon notification and using widgets here:

http://www.cnet.com/8301-19736_1-10278814-251.html

As you'll notice, there is virtually no difference between using a widget or an icon, since they can be the same size and look the same.

Comment: Are you certain that there isn't a way to hijack the Launcher's home screen and bit-blt a badge onto the image??  I want the same functionality and an appwidget is a different solution to a different problem.  Anyone can throw away my widget, but unless they uninstall the App, the icon remains true forever.

Any OS level changes in Gingerbread since this question was asked back in Eclair/Froyo days??

Comment: How about stock apps like messaging? What about `BadgeProvider`?

Comment: Please note the date on this answer! Android was very different back in 2010

Answer (score 16):

This can also be done for Sony's Xperia Home. I've blogged about it [here](http://marcusforsberg.net/blog/android-how-to-add-a-notification-badge-to-app-icon-on-sony-xperia-devices/), but the important parts are below. Sony devices use a class named `BadgeReciever`.

1. Declare the `com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE` permission in your manifest file:
2. Broadcast an `Intent` to the `BadgeReceiver`:

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent();

   intent.setAction("com.sonyericsson.home.action.UPDATE_BADGE");
   intent.putExtra("com.sonyericsson.home.intent.extra.badge.ACTIVITY_NAME", "com.yourdomain.yourapp.MainActivity");
   intent.putExtra("com.sonyericsson.home.intent.extra.badge.SHOW_MESSAGE", true);
   intent.putExtra("com.sonyericsson.home.intent.extra.badge.MESSAGE", "99");
   intent.putExtra("com.sonyericsson.home.intent.extra.badge.PACKAGE_NAME", "com.yourdomain.yourapp");

   sendBroadcast(intent);
   ```
3. Done. Once this `Intent` is broadcast the launcher should show a badge on your application icon.
4. To remove the badge again, simply send a new broadcast, this time with `SHOW_MESSAGE` set to false:

   ```
   intent.putExtra("com.sonyericsson.home.intent.extra.badge.SHOW_MESSAGE", false);
   ```

I've excluded details on how I found this to keep the answer short, but it's all available in the blog. Might be an interesting read for someone.

I've also posted a seperate SO question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216806/how-to-add-a-notification-badge-count-to-application-icon-on-sony-xperia-devices) and will add the full answer there once I'm allowed to (need 10 reputation to answer my own question within 8 hours).

Answer (score 9):

[ShortcutBadger](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger) library makes it possible and works with LG, Sony, Samsung, HTC and other custom Launchers.

It even has a way to display Badge Count in Pure Android devices desktop.

Updating the Badge Count in the application icon is as easy as calling:

```
int badgeCount = 1;
ShortcutBadger.setBadge(getApplicationContext(), badgeCount);
```

It includes a demo application that allows you to test its behaviour.

OR

you can also try activity-alias to do so, but in this you need to create different icons with badge values ,it will work great in case- you need to switch between 2 different App icons (need to create different activity-alias for displaying different icon i.e more icons = more activity-alias).

Comment: I have downloaded the zip file of ShortcutBadger and import into my AndroidStudio. When i type 10 in the EditText provided, then it will show a Toast message. But nothing is showing on icon. What we have to do

Comment: Sorry, don't get your point ..can you please make clear what you exactly want.,........as i have specify how to use shorcutBadger to set badges.

Comment: ShortcutBadger is Running Successfully after importing into Android Studio. My question is "When I enter some numbers in EditText and click on SET BADGE button, then I am unable to see any badge on App in Launcher ". Why I am not able to see this Badge.

Comment: in which device you are testing......actually this library works only in selected devices....

Comment: I am running on Emulator API 23, real Devices (Moto g, Xolo).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102229/discussion-between-demo-mail-and-gagan-deep).

Comment: Here, how to get badgeCount when app in background and push notification came?

Comment: You can use shared preferences  to save badge count and get from there when ever required.

Comment: Iam using shortcutbadger,how to get badge count when the application is closed  completely?

Comment: maintain badge count locally , and fetch it where ever required. @sahithi

Comment: unable to show badger on nexus 4 device(Manufactured by LG) android version 5.1.1

Comment: In that case,you can raise a issue on there github repo- https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger/issues

Answer (score 4):

Asus devices:

```
public static class AsusHomeBadger implements Badger {

    private static final String INTENT_ACTION = "android.intent.action.BADGE_COUNT_UPDATE";
    private static final String INTENT_EXTRA_BADGE_COUNT = "badge_count";
    private static final String INTENT_EXTRA_PACKAGENAME = "badge_count_package_name";
    private static final String INTENT_EXTRA_ACTIVITY_NAME = "badge_count_class_name";

    @Override
    public void executeBadge(int badgeCount) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(INTENT_ACTION);
        intent.putExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_BADGE_COUNT, badgeCount);
        intent.putExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_PACKAGENAME, componentName.getPackageName());
        intent.putExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_ACTIVITY_NAME, componentName.getClassName());
        intent.putExtra("badge_vip_count", 0);
        if (canResolveBroadcast(intent)) {
            AndroidUtilities.runOnUIThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ApplicationLoader.applicationContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getSupportLaunchers() {
        return Arrays.asList("com.asus.launcher");
    }
}
```

Huawei devices:

```
public static class HuaweiHomeBadger implements Badger {

    @Override
    public void executeBadge(int badgeCount) {
        final Bundle localBundle = new Bundle();
        localBundle.putString("package", ApplicationLoader.applicationContext.getPackageName());
        localBundle.putString("class", componentName.getClassName());
        localBundle.putInt("badgenumber", badgeCount);
        AndroidUtilities.runOnUIThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ApplicationLoader.applicationContext.getContentResolver().call(Uri.parse("content://com.huawei.android.launcher.settings/badge/"), "change_badge", null, localBundle);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    FileLog.e(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getSupportLaunchers() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                "com.huawei.android.launcher"
        );
    }
}
```

HTC devices:

```
public static class NewHtcHomeBadger implements Badger {

    public static final String INTENT_UPDATE_SHORTCUT = "com.htc.launcher.action.UPDATE_SHORTCUT";
    public static final String INTENT_SET_NOTIFICATION = "com.htc.launcher.action.SET_NOTIFICATION";
    public static final String PACKAGENAME = "packagename";
    public static final String COUNT = "count";
    public static final String EXTRA_COMPONENT = "com.htc.launcher.extra.COMPONENT";
    public static final String EXTRA_COUNT = "com.htc.launcher.extra.COUNT";

    @Override
    public void executeBadge(int badgeCount) {

        final Intent intent1 = new Intent(INTENT_SET_NOTIFICATION);
        intent1.putExtra(EXTRA_COMPONENT, componentName.flattenToShortString());
        intent1.putExtra(EXTRA_COUNT, badgeCount);

        final Intent intent = new Intent(INTENT_UPDATE_SHORTCUT);
        intent.putExtra(PACKAGENAME, componentName.getPackageName());
        intent.putExtra(COUNT, badgeCount);

        if (canResolveBroadcast(intent1) || canResolveBroadcast(intent)) {
            AndroidUtilities.runOnUIThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ApplicationLoader.applicationContext.sendBroadcast(intent1);
                    ApplicationLoader.applicationContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getSupportLaunchers() {
        return Arrays.asList("com.htc.launcher");
    }
}
```

Samsung devices:

```
public static class SamsungHomeBadger implements Badger {
    private static final String CONTENT_URI = "content://com.sec.badge/apps?notify=true";
    private static final String[] CONTENT_PROJECTION = new String[]{"_id","class"};

    private static DefaultBadger defaultBadger;

    @Override
    public void executeBadge(int badgeCount) {
        try {
            if (defaultBadger == null) {
                defaultBadger = new DefaultBadger();
            }
            defaultBadger.executeBadge(badgeCount);
        } catch (Exception ignore) {

        }

        Uri mUri = Uri.parse(CONTENT_URI);
        ContentResolver contentResolver = ApplicationLoader.applicationContext.getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = contentResolver.query(mUri, CONTENT_PROJECTION, "package=?", new String[]{componentName.getPackageName()}, null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                String entryActivityName = componentName.getClassName();
                boolean entryActivityExist = false;
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    int id = cursor.getInt(0);
                    ContentValues contentValues = getContentValues(componentName, badgeCount, false);
                    contentResolver.update(mUri, contentValues, "_id=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
                    if (entryActivityName.equals(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("class")))) {
                        entryActivityExist = true;
                    }
                }

                if (!entryActivityExist) {
                    ContentValues contentValues = getContentValues(componentName, badgeCount, true);
                    contentResolver.insert(mUri, contentValues);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            close(cursor);
        }
    }

    private ContentValues getContentValues(ComponentName componentName, int badgeCount, boolean isInsert) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        if (isInsert) {
            contentValues.put("package", componentName.getPackageName());
            contentValues.put("class", componentName.getClassName());
        }

        contentValues.put("badgecount", badgeCount);

        return contentValues;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getSupportLaunchers() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                "com.sec.android.app.launcher",
                "com.sec.android.app.twlauncher"
        );
    }
}
```

Sony devices:

```
public static class SonyHomeBadger implements Badger {

    private static final String INTENT_ACTION = "com.sonyericsson.home.action.UPDATE_BADGE";
    private static final String INTENT_EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.sonyericsson.home.intent.extra.badge.PACKAGE_NAME";
    private static final String INTENT_EXTRA_ACTIVITY_NAME = "com.sonyericsson.home.intent.extra.badge.ACTIVITY_NAME";
    private static final String INTENT_EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.sonyericsson.home.intent.extra.badge.MESSAGE";
    private static final String INTENT_EXTRA_SHOW_MESSAGE = "com.sonyericsson.home.intent.extra.badge.SHOW_MESSAGE";

    private static final String PROVIDER_CONTENT_URI = "content://com.sonymobile.home.resourceprovider/badge";
    private static final String PROVIDER_COLUMNS_BADGE_COUNT = "badge_count";
    private static final String PROVIDER_COLUMNS_PACKAGE_NAME = "package_name";
    private static final String PROVIDER_COLUMNS_ACTIVITY_NAME = "activity_name";
    private static final String SONY_HOME_PROVIDER_NAME = "com.sonymobile.home.resourceprovider";
    private final Uri BADGE_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse(PROVIDER_CONTENT_URI);

    private static AsyncQueryHandler mQueryHandler;

    @Override
    public void executeBadge(int badgeCount) {
        if (sonyBadgeContentProviderExists()) {
            executeBadgeByContentProvider(badgeCount);
        } else {
            executeBadgeByBroadcast(badgeCount);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getSupportLaunchers() {
        return Arrays.asList("com.sonyericsson.home", "com.sonymobile.home");
    }

    private static void executeBadgeByBroadcast(int badgeCount) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(INTENT_ACTION);
        intent.putExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, componentName.getPackageName());
        intent.putExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_ACTIVITY_NAME, componentName.getClassName());
        intent.putExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_MESSAGE, String.valueOf(badgeCount));
        intent.putExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_SHOW_MESSAGE, badgeCount > 0);
        AndroidUtilities.runOnUIThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ApplicationLoader.applicationContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    private void executeBadgeByContentProvider(int badgeCount) {
        if (badgeCount < 0) {
            return;
        }

        if (mQueryHandler == null) {
            mQueryHandler = new AsyncQueryHandler(ApplicationLoader.applicationContext.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver()) {

                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    try {
                        super.handleMessage(msg);
                    } catch (Throwable ignore) {

                    }
                }
            };
        }
        insertBadgeAsync(badgeCount, componentName.getPackageName(), componentName.getClassName());
    }

    private void insertBadgeAsync(int badgeCount, String packageName, String activityName) {
        final ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(PROVIDER_COLUMNS_BADGE_COUNT, badgeCount);
        contentValues.put(PROVIDER_COLUMNS_PACKAGE_NAME, packageName);
        contentValues.put(PROVIDER_COLUMNS_ACTIVITY_NAME, activityName);
        mQueryHandler.startInsert(0, null, BADGE_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
    }

    private static boolean sonyBadgeContentProviderExists() {
        boolean exists = false;
        ProviderInfo info = ApplicationLoader.applicationContext.getPackageManager().resolveContentProvider(SONY_HOME_PROVIDER_NAME, 0);
        if (info != null) {
            exists = true;
        }
        return exists;
    }
}
```

Xiaomi devices:

```
public static class XiaomiHomeBadger implements Badger {

    public static final String INTENT_ACTION = "android.intent.action.APPLICATION_MESSAGE_UPDATE";
    public static final String EXTRA_UPDATE_APP_COMPONENT_NAME = "android.intent.extra.update_application_component_name";
    public static final String EXTRA_UPDATE_APP_MSG_TEXT = "android.intent.extra.update_application_message_text";

    @Override
    public void executeBadge(int badgeCount) {
        try {
            Class miuiNotificationClass = Class.forName("android.app.MiuiNotification");
            Object miuiNotification = miuiNotificationClass.newInstance();
            Field field = miuiNotification.getClass().getDeclaredField("messageCount");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(miuiNotification, String.valueOf(badgeCount == 0 ? "" : badgeCount));
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            final Intent localIntent = new Intent(INTENT_ACTION);
            localIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_UPDATE_APP_COMPONENT_NAME, componentName.getPackageName() + "/" + componentName.getClassName());
            localIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_UPDATE_APP_MSG_TEXT, String.valueOf(badgeCount == 0 ? "" : badgeCount));
            if (canResolveBroadcast(localIntent)) {
                AndroidUtilities.runOnUIThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ApplicationLoader.applicationContext.sendBroadcast(localIntent);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getSupportLaunchers() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                "com.miui.miuilite",
                "com.miui.home",
                "com.miui.miuihome",
                "com.miui.miuihome2",
                "com.miui.mihome",
                "com.miui.mihome2"
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of API 26, this is now [officially supported](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/badges):

> Starting with 8.0 (API level 26), notification badges (also known as notification dots) appear on a launcher icon when the associated app has an active notification. Users can long-press on the app icon to reveal the notifications (alongside any app shortcuts), as shown in figure 1.
>
> **These dots appear by default in launcher apps that support them and there's nothing your app needs to do**. However, there might be situations in which you don't want the to notification dot to appear or you want to control exactly which notifications to appear there.

To set a custom number, call setNumber() on the notification:

```
mNotification.setNumber(messageCount)
```

Comment: How do you get it on the side of what's supposed to show it? Can apps that aren't the default launcher be able to get this information?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it for:

- [Apex Launcher](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1930365)
- [Nova Launcer](http://novalauncher.com/teslaunread-api/)

I think there's also a way to do it on the LG launcher, but haven't found out how yet.