# add a number on the android application launch icon

Tags: android, cordova

everyone,

I 'm now wanna add a push and pull function in my phonegap app(android).and I wanna add a number in the lauch icon to notify user there are some unread messages.
BTW,My android app is writen by phonegap.is there any method given by phonegap can do this,or I should use some plugin?

is there any one know how to do this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You mean missed call count just like iPhone?This may be related to launcher.Some launcher like MIUI have already implements this function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to add a badge to an application icon in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905542/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-badge-to-an-application-icon-in-android)

Comment: can you tell me more details,many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

android doesnt allow changing of the application drawable icon.  there is no way to programmatically change it.

u can try using a widget though to do what u want. check this out.  http://www.cnet.com/8301-19736_1-10278814-251.html

Comment: It seems that I can't create widgets while I use phonegap to build android app.if it means it's a impossible task? Many Thanks!