# Android: Show Notifications on launcher icon

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, notifications

How to show notifications on launcher icon(such as native Messages,email app) in android like iphone.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to add a badge to an application icon in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905542/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-badge-to-an-application-icon-in-android)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android **doesnt** provide a way to do this. It always references the same  app launcher icon when you compile your project into an apk. There is **no way** to change this later on. A widget can be an alternative.

Comment: Way to do this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565307/how-to-display-count-of-notifications-in-app-launcher-icon