# How to display count of notifications in app launcher icon

Tags: android, android-layout, notifications, icons

samsung galaxy note 2 android version 4.1.2

I know that this question was asked before and the reply was not possible

> How to display balloon counter over application launcher icon on
>   android

Nevertheless yesterday I updated the facebook app and it started to show a counter of unread messages private messages. How come facebook app can and I cant do so for my app?

[image: facebook icon]

[image]

samsung galaxy note 2 android version 4.1.2

Comment: Is this on your list of app or on your home screen?

Comment: list of apps not the home screen

Comment: People open your eyes please.It's TouchWiz not Vanilla Android. Please provide evidence of seeing these badges on a stock Android home screen, such as one of the Nexus series devices.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203541/how-to-give-counter-if-more-than-one-notifications-are-there
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381157/how-to-count-number-of-notification-and-display-single-icon-in-android

Comment: android version 4.1.2

Comment: Its not just touchWiz, i can see same thing on my sony xperia S phone

Comment: Here's the how-to for doing this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136483/how-do-you-interface-with-badgeprovider-on-samsung-phones/20136484#20136484

Comment: There is a nice library that seems to gather many ways to show badges, for multiple launchers : https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger/

Comment: You can! From the doc: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/badges

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Android ("vanilla" android without custom launchers and touch interfaces) **does not** allow changing of the application icon, because it is sealed in the `.apk` tightly once the program is compiled. There is no way to change it to a 'drawable' programmatically using standard APIs. You may achieve your goal by using a widget instead of an icon. Widgets are customisable. Please read this :http://www.cnet.com/8301-19736_1-10278814-251.html and this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html.
Also look here: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger. It can help you.

As for badge numbers. As I said before - there is no standard way for doing this. But we all know that Android is an open operating system and we can do everything we want with it, so the only way to add a badge number - is either to use some 3-rd party apps or custom launchers, or front-end touch interfaces: Samsung TouchWiz or Sony Xperia's interface. Other answers use this capabilities and you can search for this on stackoverflow, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216806/how-to-add-a-notification-badge-count-to-application-icon-on-sony-xperia-devices). But I will repeat one more time: there is **no** standard API for this and I want to say it is a *bad* practice. App's icon notification badge is an iOS pattern and it should not be used in Android apps anyway. In Andrioid there is a status bar notifications for these purposes:http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html 
So, if Facebook or someone other use this - it is not a common pattern or trend we should consider. But if you insist anyway and don't want to use home screen widgets then look here, please:

[How does Facebook add badge numbers on app icon in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510419/how-does-facebook-add-badge-numbers-on-app-icon-in-android)

As you see this is not an actual Facebook app it's TouchWiz. In vanilla android this can be achieved with Nova Launcher http://forums.androidcentral.com/android-applications/199709-how-guide-global-badge-notifications.html
So if you will see icon badges somewhere, be sure it is either a 3-rd party launcher or touch interface (frontend wrapper). May be sometime Google will add this capability to the standard Android API.

Comment: this is not a widget this is in the apps tab

Comment: Widgets are customisable you are right. Use widget instead of an icon. Good idea. Thank you.

Comment: @user2443241 Please refer this question especially CommonsWare answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android
If you even in some ugly and dirty way (like changing manifest) will update  your icon programmatically then you will not be able to sign your app.And please look at edits I did for my answer.

Comment: take a look at the image i just added

Comment: @user2443241 Please told me what Android device you use. I think Facebook use some kind of TouchWiz API http://techcrunch.com/2009/08/17/samsung-opens-up-touchwiz-widget-development/
But if you have vanilla android device without Nova then i think Facebook use some kind of dirty magic for this...

Comment: samsung galaxy note 2 android version 4.1.2

Comment: @user2443241 Then please look here 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TouchWiz
I'm sick of explaining and giving proof links that this badge feature not pure Android but TouchWiz layer. On my Nexus 4 which is stock Android smartphone my Facebook app didn't show any badges. I give you a detailed explanations. I don't want to explain something more.Good luck

Comment: ok so this will work on some samsung devices, cool. Ok thank, i think it is worth doing since samsung is wide spread. :)

Comment: @Till now TouchWiz has a proprietary API.But Samsung announce that soon they will make it public: http://developer.samsung.com/android
Refer also this useful answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864184/how-do-i-set-up-htc-sense-and-samsung-touchwiz-app-icon-badges
If I help in some way you can accept my answer other people will see it.

Comment: You can! From the doc: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/badges

Answer (score 94):

It works in samsung touchwiz launcher

```
public static void setBadge(Context context, int count) {
    String launcherClassName = getLauncherClassName(context);
    if (launcherClassName == null) {
        return;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.BADGE_COUNT_UPDATE");
    intent.putExtra("badge_count", count);
    intent.putExtra("badge_count_package_name", context.getPackageName());
    intent.putExtra("badge_count_class_name", launcherClassName);
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}

public static String getLauncherClassName(Context context) {

    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resolveInfos) {
        String pkgName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName;
        if (pkgName.equalsIgnoreCase(context.getPackageName())) {
            String className = resolveInfo.activityInfo.name;
            return className;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: can u tell me how to clear badge?

Comment: @DixitPatel That is simple. Just "setBadge(context, 0)"

Comment: Its always good when the answer is simple to understand!1 Cheers ChangUZ

Comment: Can it show a character or string like, say a star '*' instead of a counter which is an integer?

Comment: NICE JOB, WORKS PERFECT, SET: positive number, UNSET: negative number or 0

Comment: Thanks its working...@ChangUZ

Comment: Awesome and clear, so great, simply ¡ PERFECT !

Comment: Not working for Micromax Canvas. Could you please help me?

Comment: in versions 4.0.2 not work why ?

Comment: Alternative solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20136484/1617737

Comment: Does it need some permissions?

Comment: @ChangUZ Nice! Where's the best place to put this code? Are you running this also when the app is in the background?

Comment: Can I change the color of bagde ?>

Comment: hi guys, i had a doubt, i cannot set manually badge count, its possible, without notifiactions

Comment: @ChangUZ I am able to set it to my current app with this method. Is it possible to set the badge_count to other 3rd party apps?

Comment: not working on Samsung galaxy S8 plus Oreo

Answer (score 82):

[ShortcutBadger](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger) is a library that adds an abstraction layer over the device brand and current launcher and offers a great result. Works with LG, Sony, Samsung, HTC and other custom Launchers.

It even has a way to display Badge Count in Pure Android devices desktop.

Updating the Badge Count in the application icon is as easy as calling:

```
int badgeCount = 1;
ShortcutBadger.applyCount(context, badgeCount);
```

It includes a demo application that allows you to test its behavior.

Comment: Thanks, It's work well, But I wonder how apps like Line, What's app, Solmail etc. uses badge without those lots of permissions. Any Idea?

Comment: @Virusman, i think that this kind of permissions are not displayed to the user. You can test it by installing the Sample App from the apk. However, it should not be a problem to include permissions that are needed.

Comment: Yes I only saw samsung's permissions among all of them during installation, But I decompiled Line app and didn't see any of badge permissions there.

Comment: @AlexGuti Thanks for your efficient answer.
ShortcutBadger is working fine on Sony and Saamsung but how to use with Nexus device.

Comment: The Nexus (pure Android) devices will display badge count only on icons in desktop

Comment: It seems not support Huawei , cause I have tested Huawei P7.

Comment: @Leo.Han, in the docs it's said that Huawei is supported for version 1.1.7+

Comment: @AlexGuti, yeah, I saw the docs. I used v1.1.8, but it still didn't work. I checked out that Huawei needs a certificate which needs to be applied in Huawei Official website, and then your App can use the badge API.

Comment: For using this, we need to add persmission for each device seprately and  for sony devices suppose your using it without persmission, it will crash even you use try catch around. for other devices like Huawei honor holly,its not crashing

Comment: this library do not work in Android 7.0 and above. I check it with nexus 5x and nexus 6.

Comment: @Kenji, i just tried the demo app on a Galaxy S7 with Android 7 and works perfect. I tried it previously on Nexus devices with Android 4 and only worked for icons on desktop, not app launcher

Comment: Here, how to get badgeCount when app in background and push notification came?

Comment: @Avi If you are implementing FCM then you will have to extend a `GcmReceiver` for more have a look at https://medium.com/@deividi/a-good-way-to-handle-incoming-notifications-in-android-dc64c29041a5

Comment: Not working when the app is the background or killed

Answer (score 12):

I have figured out how this is done for Sony devices.

I've blogged about it [here](http://marcusforsberg.net/blog/android-how-to-add-a-notification-badge-to-app-icon-on-sony-xperia-devices/). I've also posted a seperate SO question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216806/how-to-add-a-notification-badge-count-to-application-icon-on-sony-xperia-devices).

---

Sony devices use a class named `BadgeReciever`.

1. Declare the `com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE` permission in your manifest file:
2. Broadcast an `Intent` to the `BadgeReceiver`:

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent();

   intent.setAction("com.sonyericsson.home.action.UPDATE_BADGE");
   intent.putExtra("com.sonyericsson.home.intent.extra.badge.ACTIVITY_NAME", "com.yourdomain.yourapp.MainActivity");
   intent.putExtra("com.sonyericsson.home.intent.extra.badge.SHOW_MESSAGE", true);
   intent.putExtra("com.sonyericsson.home.intent.extra.badge.MESSAGE", "99");
   intent.putExtra("com.sonyericsson.home.intent.extra.badge.PACKAGE_NAME", "com.yourdomain.yourapp");

   sendBroadcast(intent);
   ```
3. Done. Once this `Intent` is broadcast the launcher should show a badge on your application icon.
4. To remove the badge again, simply send a new broadcast, this time with `SHOW_MESSAGE` set to false:

   ```
   intent.putExtra("com.sonyericsson.home.intent.extra.badge.SHOW_MESSAGE", false);
   ```

I've excluded details on how I found this to keep the answer short, but it's all available in the blog. Might be an interesting read for someone.

Comment: Hi Marcus, shall i try the above same for Moto cPlus mobile models?. is it for specifically for particular devices or common for all android mobiles

Comment: @harikrishnan As stated in the answer, this is only for Sony phones. However, you can check out AlexGutis response above for a library that solves this for several models - perhaps also for Moto phones.

Comment: thank you for reply Marcus. I have tried already for AlexGutis ShortcutBadger answer. but, its not working for my moto model.

Comment: The url to your blog is a broken link! Can you please update the link ?

Answer (score 11):

This is sample and best way for showing badge on notification launcher icon.

Add This Class in your application

```
public class BadgeUtils {

    public static void setBadge(Context context, int count) {
        setBadgeSamsung(context, count);
        setBadgeSony(context, count);
    }

    public static void clearBadge(Context context) {
        setBadgeSamsung(context, 0);
        clearBadgeSony(context);
    }


    private static void setBadgeSamsung(Context context, int count) {
        String launcherClassName = getLauncherClassName(context);
        if (launcherClassName == null) {
            return;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.BADGE_COUNT_UPDATE");
        intent.putExtra("badge_count", count);
        intent.putExtra("badge_count_package_name", context.getPackageName());
        intent.putExtra("badge_count_class_name", launcherClassName);
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    private static void setBadgeSony(Context context, int count) {
        String launcherClassName = getLauncherClassName(context);
        if (launcherClassName == null) {
            return;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("com.sonyericsson.home.action.UPDATE_BADGE");
        intent.putExtra("com.sonyericsson.home.intent.extra.badge.ACTIVITY_NAME", launcherClassName);
        intent.putExtra("com.sonyericsson.home.intent.extra.badge.SHOW_MESSAGE", true);
        intent.putExtra("com.sonyericsson.home.intent.extra.badge.MESSAGE", String.valueOf(count));
        intent.putExtra("com.sonyericsson.home.intent.extra.badge.PACKAGE_NAME", context.getPackageName());

        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }


    private static void clearBadgeSony(Context context) {
        String launcherClassName = getLauncherClassName(context);
        if (launcherClassName == null) {
            return;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("com.sonyericsson.home.action.UPDATE_BADGE");
        intent.putExtra("com.sonyericsson.home.intent.extra.badge.ACTIVITY_NAME", launcherClassName);
        intent.putExtra("com.sonyericsson.home.intent.extra.badge.SHOW_MESSAGE", false);
        intent.putExtra("com.sonyericsson.home.intent.extra.badge.MESSAGE", String.valueOf(0));
        intent.putExtra("com.sonyericsson.home.intent.extra.badge.PACKAGE_NAME", context.getPackageName());

        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    private static String getLauncherClassName(Context context) {

        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resolveInfos) {
            String pkgName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName;
            if (pkgName.equalsIgnoreCase(context.getPackageName())) {
                String className = resolveInfo.activityInfo.name;
                return className;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


}
```

==> MyGcmListenerService.java
Use BadgeUtils  class when notification comes.

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService { 

    private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService"; 
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {

            String message = data.getString("Msg");
            String Type = data.getString("Type"); 
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

            NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigTextStyle= new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();

            bigTextStyle .setBigContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .bigText(message);
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
                    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setStyle(bigTextStyle) 
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.appColor);
            notificationBuilder.setColor(color);
            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


            int unOpenCount=AppUtill.getPreferenceInt("NOTICOUNT",this);
            unOpenCount=unOpenCount+1;

            AppUtill.savePreferenceLong("NOTICOUNT",unOpenCount,this);  
            notificationManager.notify(unOpenCount /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build()); 

// This is for bladge on home icon          
        BadgeUtils.setBadge(MyGcmListenerService.this,(int)unOpenCount);

    }


    private int getNotificationIcon() {
        boolean useWhiteIcon = (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP);
        return useWhiteIcon ? R.drawable.notification_small_icon : R.drawable.icon_launcher;
    }
}
```

And clear notification from preference and also with badge count

```
 public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 
                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

                    AppUtill.savePreferenceLong("NOTICOUNT",0,this);
                    BadgeUtils.clearBadge(this);
            }
    }
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE" />
```

Comment: It appears to only work on sony phones

Comment: This is working in Sony , HTC and Samsung device also.