# Change I put a small notification or text on my app icon in android

Tags: android, android-manifest

I want to assign a text on my app icon like "new" or anything in android? can i do through code in android & when app is installed it always show that message on app icon

Comment: Can you brief what you require , your question is not clear

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565307/how-to-display-count-of-notifications-in-app-launcher-icon

Comment: In Your manifest file inside application element give the name what you want to see on the icon of your app. do it like this
android:label="@string/app_name" where app name is the name what you want to give to your app.