# Android Button Notifications like messages button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-notifications, android-button

Does anyone have an idea of how the message button, notifies and updates us on the top corner how many unread messages are there and how do you do it. Thanks in advance this is a sample picture of what i want,

[image]

And this a sample usual xml code for a button in android,

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/bAddRec"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/add" />
```

And I hope that your answers will be useful to others as well :)

Comment: No men this is not possible in Android but instead of you can implement this type of functionality using `AppWidget` in Android.

Comment: You want to do it within app or on app icon in app drawer?

Comment: You have to use Framelayout having a button and a imageview. Make visibilty of imageview according to notification.

Comment: @Manish Dubey I just want to learn both wihin the App and for the App icon :) Please provide more solutions if possible :)

Comment: @Gaurav Berry Thanks for your information I grabbed some ideas for the task :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at this ViewBager lib..it will help you

In this yourView is placed in framelayout with top right cornor badge indicating unread msg or count or any thing....

[ViewBager liberary](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger)

Comment: Thank you very much your link was very useful hope i can learn it quickly and implement them in my Apps :)

Answer (score 1):

Android doesn't support this kind of practice because it has notification bar for this kind of purpose. But if you need it really bad then, you Samsung and Sony Xperia provides you with a way to do it.

This might be helpfulto you :
[How to display count of notifications in app launcher icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565307/how-to-display-count-of-notifications-in-app-launcher-icon)