# Android unread message count display on app icon

Tags: android, android-widget, widget, badge

I want to add an unread message count update in application icon for android (like ios devices). After searching i came to know that the only solution is to make a widget look like app icon. I created a widget but i don't know how to replace my launcher icon with this widget? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: how u got unread message count ? @AnilKumar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to replace launcher icon with widget. You can say to user to place your widget on the home screen, but not in application list. Users must do that in their own.
Nevertheless, it's iOs pattern. It's not good idea to bring iOS design elements to android. Android have great notification bar, where user expect to see notification from your app. Android users don't expect to see it over the icon.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, You can't do that on application icon. Android doesn't allow that. Instead you can have app widgets for this. Further details defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565307/how-to-display-count-of-notifications-in-app-launcher-icon). It might help

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a new launcher on your phone such as Nova Launcher which replaces your stock Android Launcher.

Then you can customize which icons show unread messages via apps such as missedit and others.

Good luck