# How to push notification count on android app icon

Tags: android, push-notification, badge

When PushNotification coming from GCM. i got one count number based on that i need to show a count on my android app icon in my device applications list.

Comment: That is not possible in Android but instead of you can do it using `App Widget Provider` in Android.

Comment: Not all Android OS support this.

Comment: @SimplePlan is there any example code for App Widget Provider

Comment: @user3594991 ya off course [Example of App Widget Provider](https://www.google.co.in/#q=app+widget+provider+example+in+android&spell=1)

Comment: @user3594991 ask to make webservice from back end person!

Comment: @HemantChandDungriyal i'm asked PHP person he sent message and count keys.

Comment: @user3594991 show count number on android app icon

Comment: @HemantChandDungriyal how to show count number on android app icon. i don't no this coding please help me

Comment: @user3594991 i think u need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565307/how-to-display-count-of-notifications-in-app-launcher-icon