# How to set notification count in both notification area and desktop notification like facebook?

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I have followed these [tutorial](http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/) and I got that notification. But I want to set the count and make it visible with the icon and I want to drag and close the notification like facebook.

This is my code. To increase the notification I have followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565307/how-to-display-count-of-notifications-in-app-launcher-icon)

```
 @Override 
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    context = this;
    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
              R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    chatHead = new ImageView(this);
    chatHead.setImageBitmap(getCircleBitmap(bm, 200));
    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 100;
    setBadge(context, count++);
    chatHead.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
          private int initialX;
          private int initialY;
          private float initialTouchX;
          private float initialTouchY;
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (event.getAction()) {
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                initialX = params.x;
                initialY = params.y;
                initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                initialTouchY = event.getRawY();

                return true;
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                return true;
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatHead, params);

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    windowManager.addView(chatHead, params);

  }
  public static void setBadge(Context context, int count) {
        String launcherClassName = getLauncherClassName(context);
        if (launcherClassName == null) {
            return;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.BADGE_COUNT_UPDATE");
        intent.putExtra("badge_count", count);
        intent.putExtra("badge_count_package_name", context.getPackageName());
        intent.putExtra("badge_count_class_name", launcherClassName);
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    public static String getLauncherClassName(Context context) {

        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resolveInfos) {
            String pkgName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName;
            if (pkgName.equalsIgnoreCase(context.getPackageName())) {
                String className = resolveInfo.activityInfo.name;
                return className;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      return START_STICKY;
  }
  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (chatHead != null) windowManager.removeView(chatHead);
  }
  private Bitmap getCircleBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {
      final Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
       bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
      final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
     // int pixels;
      final int color = 0xff424242;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
        final float roundPx = pixels;
        paint.setShadowLayer(2, 2, 2, 0xff424242);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

      paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
      canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

      bitmap.recycle();

      return output;
     }
```

I also want to make it visible the count with `GCM` notification. I set the count with the GCM message. But it is not visible.

```
private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    int numMessages = 0;
    Intent inservice = new Intent(this, ChatService.class);
    startService(inservice);
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
            .setContentTitle("Contact Received")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setContentText(msg)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setNumber(numMessages++)
            .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" +R.raw.sounds1));
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Could anyone give me some working example?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a way to do this if you mean for it to be in the notifications window. If it's in the notification window, you should consider using the [number attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#number) for notifications.

If you insist on using a badge like element, you can check out [Android ViewBadger](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger), but I don't think you can use this in your notifications window.