# How to set notification count budge on the application icon in android

Tags: android, push-notification

i want to set notification count budge on the application icon likes **Gmail**,**Message** application in android mobile

**Note** : Without using third party application

Answer (score 1):

To create an App Widget and create a widget remote layout for your applications.

1.Create receiver for applications
2.Update the widget view any updates will get

You can redirect developer site 
[Android Widget](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)

Comment: this link for  widget  how to make widget but i don't want like this. I want to set notification count on application icon like IPhone application and in android gmail counter budget

Comment: not possible via android API - see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565307/how-to-display-count-of-notifications-in-app-launcher-icon/24804467#24804467)