# Add unread notification badge on android app icon

Tags: android

I use eclipse IDE for develop android applications.

I want to show notification badge on android app icon for all android devices but i did not find solution for that. How does i implement this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display count of notifications in app launcher icon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565307/how-to-display-count-of-notifications-in-app-launcher-icon)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An Android library named `ShortcutBadger` makes your android app showing the count of unread messages as a badge on your app icon. Try it.

https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger

Using `android-viewbadger` lib you can easily create `badge` on any given android view at runtime without having to cater for it in layout.

https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger

Comment: For use this lib i need to add repositories and dependencies. its maven based project and i use eclipse. In which file i add this in eclipse project?

Comment: You can open it in android studio.

Comment: I tried ShortcutBadger and it runs successfully but my project is eclipse project and i want solution based on eclipse project. Also this is for limited device. Is that any another solution for eclipse project and for all android devices?

Comment: look at this : [Importing Android Studio projects into Eclipse](http://www.101apps.co.za/articles/importing-android-studio-projects-into-eclipse.html)

Comment: converting in eclipse its also works but is that any solution for other devices?

Comment: I think this is only available solution so far I know.

Comment: hi patel, i had a similar doubt, this is only working on sms notifications or manually set the badges