# Windows 10 Mobile AppBar Button - Badge count

Tags: windows, mobile, uwp, badge

is there any chance to put badge count to the AppBarButton control on Windows 10, as you can do it on Android - e.g. [How to display count of notifications in app launcher icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565307/how-to-display-count-of-notifications-in-app-launcher-icon)

If not, any idea what is a good practice to inform user about some new information (like new message)?

thanks!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjHNt.png

Comment: Are you trying to display badge information on the app's tile (similar to the Android app launcher you link) or on an app bar within the app? For the former start with https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185606.aspx

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for your reaction. I'm trying to do something like on the screenshot I've put above. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to create a control in an UWP app like your second picture, you can do it like below:

```xml
<Button Background="Transparent" Click="OnClick" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <RelativePanel>
        <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="30" Text="&#xE90A;"/>
        <Border Background="Red" RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True">
            <TextBlock x:Name="count" Foreground="White" Text="{x:Bind tb.Text,Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="12" />
        </Border>
    </RelativePanel>
</Button>
<TextBox VerticalAlignment="Bottom" x:Name="tb" />
```

In this sample, I bind the Text of the `TextBlock` named "count" to a `TextBox`, so we can change this value.

But we can create it as an [UserControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.usercontrol.aspx), so that we can use it repeatable. And we can use a [DependencyProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyproperty.aspx) to expose the property we want to use. For example here:

```xml
<UserControl
    x:Class="BadgeCountApp.MyUserControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:BadgeCountApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Button Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <RelativePanel>
            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="30" x:Name="text" Text="{x:Bind SymbText,Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <Border Background="Red" RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True">
                <TextBlock x:Name="count" Foreground="White" FontSize="12" Text="{x:Bind SymbCount,Mode=OneWay}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            </Border>
        </RelativePanel>
    </Button>

</UserControl>
```

code behind:

```cs
public sealed partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SymbTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SymbText", typeof(string), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SymbCountProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SymbCount", typeof(int), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(0, new PropertyChangedCallback(ChangedCallback)));

    private static void ChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyUserControl muc = (MyUserControl)d;
        int value = (int)e.NewValue;

        if (value == 0)
        {
            muc.count.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else
        {
            muc.count.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }

    public string SymbText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(SymbTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SymbTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public int SymbCount
    {
        get{ return (int)GetValue(SymbCountProperty);}
        set{ SetValue(SymbCountProperty, value);}
    }

}
```

Now you can use this control directly in other place like this:

```xml
<local:MyUserControl x:Name="user" SymbText="&#xE90A;" Tapped="OnTapped"/>
```

code behind:

```cs
private void OnTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (user.SymbCount == 0)
        user.SymbCount = 3;
    else
        user.SymbCount = 0;
}
```

The following is a screenshot of this `UserControl`:
[image]

Comment: Hi Grace, thanks a lot for such great and deep explanation. Can we use custom usercontrols in AppBar as well? I've read that AppBar is managed exclusively by system, so there is no such thing like customize buttons inside. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, actually we can use a usercontrol in AppBar,  like this:   <Page.TopAppBar>
        <CommandBar>
            <CommandBar.Content>
                <Grid>
                    <local:MyUserControl x:Name="user" SymbCount="3" SymbText="&#xE90A;" Tapped="OnTapped"/>
                </Grid>
            </CommandBar.Content>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Accept" Label="appbarbutton"/>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Cancel" Label="appbarbutton"/>
        </CommandBar>
    </Page.TopAppBar>