# Show current date with month in Launcher icon

Tags: android, calendar, icons

Hellow , I have one question related to launcher icon in android. Is it possible to show current date with month in launcher icon like IOS in which the date changes everyday? If possible,how?

Comment: I think that [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android) could help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android does not support Badges like iOS. You can not show Badge/Count in your launcher icon.

Some of the vendor (I saw it in some Samsung phones) do support such feature for which they provide additional details. If you wish you can implement for such devices.

You can also refer [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565307/how-to-display-count-of-notifications-in-app-launcher-icon) for additional details.