# When an app is in background, onMessageReceived method is not firing

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, badge

Actually i need to show badge in app icon but i don't know how to get badge and why onMessageReceived not call when app is in background or app is not running.

```
public class Custom_FirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService          {
            private static final String TAG = "FirebaseMsgService";
            String activityName;

            @Override
            public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

                if (remoteMessage == null)
                    return;
                if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
                }
                // Check if message contains a data payload.
                if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());
                    try{
                        //boolean from_bg = Boolean.parseBoolean(remoteMessage.getData().get("from_bg").toString());
                        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
                        boolean show_fg =  Boolean.parseBoolean(data.get("show_fg"));
                        .....
```

Comment: if you want to receive message while in background, you have to use payload data, as described in https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: Can you tell which device you are using ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle notification when app in background in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase)

Comment: to be called onMessageReceived all time (app foreground or background), You need to receive "data" payload only (not both "data" & "notification" payload). if You send both "data" & "notification" payload, when app is in the foreground, "onMessageReceived" will be called for that time.

Comment: me send both "data" & "notification" payload and onMessageReceived in foreground but not in background, you have any idea about show badge in app icon ?

Comment: I don't know how to get badge.

Answer (score 3):

There are two types of FCM

`notification` Messages: Sending a payload with this message type triggers `onMessageReceived()` only when your app is in foreground.

`data` Messages: Sending a payload with *only* this specific message type triggers `onMessageReceived()` regardless if your app is in foreground/background.

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages

Comment: You misused a terminology. There is no such thing as *Display* messages, it should be `notification` messages. The description is close but not at all accurate. Please modify them to be more precise as to what is shown in the docs or better yet, refer to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) completely

Comment: @AL. Thanks for your valuable advice.

Comment: No problem. Cheers!

Comment: @AL have any idea about show badge at app icon like facebook?

Comment: @Avi [No standard way of doing it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17565479/4625829).

Answer (score 0):

Add service to `AndroidManifest.xml`. Also make sure token is not expired.

```
<service android:name=".FirebaseMessagingService">
 <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
 </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Refresh Token if it is expired.

```
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

    // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
    // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
    // Instance ID token to your app server.
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}
```

Comment: I already did this:

<service
            android:name=".fcmnotification.Custom_FirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>