# Cannot "open" notification that is received when the app is in background

Tags: android, django, react-native, push-notification, react-android

i have a problem when i want to process notification that is received when the app is in the background. I do receive the notification, when i click on the notification, the app opens however the FCM.on method is not executed at all, it seems it does not handle the callback.

When the app is in the foreground everything is working fine, and it process the notification without any problems.

This is the code in react-native

```
FCM.on(FCMEvent.Notification, notif => {
      switch(notif.fcm.action){
        case 'fcm.ACTION.HANDLEMESSAGE':
          var data = {
            thread: notif.pk,
            message: JSON.parse(notif.message)
          }

          this.props.dispatch(fcmMSG(data));
          this.props.dispatch(addNotification(notif.pk, notif.job_id));
          break;

        case "fcm.ACTION.HANDLEAPPLICATION":
          axios.get(newServerURL + "/jobs/companyJobDetails/" + notif.recruitJobId + "/")
              .then((response) => {
                  var jobMainRecruits = response.data;
                  const {navigator} = this.refs;
                  navigator.push({
                  jobMainRecruits,
                  });
            })
              .catch((error) => {
                  console.log("ERROR")
            });        
          break;

        default:
      }
    });  
FCM.getInitialNotification().then(notif => {
      switch(notif.fcm.action){
        case 'fcm.ACTION.HANDLEMESSAGE':

          const { navigator } = this.refs;

          var thread = {
            candidate: notif.candidate,
            company: notif.company,
            candidate_avatar: notif.candidate_avatar,
            candidate_first_name: notif.candidate_first_name,
            candidate_last_name: notif.candidate_last_name,

            job_id: notif.job_id,
            pk: notif.pk,
            subject: notif.subject,
            message: JSON.parse(notif.message)
          }

          navigator.push({
            thread,
          });

          break;
        case "fcm.ACTION.HANDLEAPPLICATION":
          axios.get(newServerURL + "/jobs/companyJobDetails/" + notif.recruitJobId + "/")
              .then((response) => {
                  var jobMainMessages = response.data;
                  const {navigator} = this.refs;
                  navigator.push({
                  jobMainMessages,
                  });
            })
              .catch((error) => {
                  console.log("ERROR")
            });          
          break;

        default:

      }
    })
```

EDIT:
this is my code in the backend

```
push_service = FCMNotification(api_key=FCM_API_KEY)
                    registration_id = token.token
                    message_title = jobInfo.title
                    message_body = "New application"
                    message_icon = 'ic_launcher'
                    sound = 'Default'
                    color = '#362F64'
                    click_action='fcm.ACTION.NEWJOBAPPLICATION'
                    data_message = {'recruitJobId': self.request.data['job'], 'message_title': message_title, 'message_body': message_body}
                    result = push_service.notify_single_device(click_action=click_action, registration_id=registration_id, message_title=message_title, message_body=message_body, message_icon=message_icon, sound=sound, data_message=data_message, color=color)
```

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Look this one :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase

Comment: See this :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/44152075/4448617

Comment: i think i/m already sending data(typeload) so i dont think the problem is in the configuration

Answer (score 1):

> The initial notification contains the notification that launches the
>   app. If the user launches the app by clicking the banner, the banner
>   notification info will be here rather than through FCM.on event.
>   sometimes Android kills activity when the app goes to background, and
>   then resume it broadcasts notification before JS is run. You can use
>   `FCM.getInitialNotification()` to capture those missed events. [source](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm#usage)

```
FCM.getInitialNotification().then(notif => {
    // do some logic here
   // I usually add this function inside my root page
});
```

Comment: ah sorry i have it on my getInitialNotificiation as well... Forgot to post that part. Also that code as well is not execute when i resume my app from the background