# Android push notification badge counter on Home Screen

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-settings

For Facebook/Whatsapp/Twitter, there is this option on the notification setting page of Android:
"**Home screen app icon badge**" screenshot attached.
[image]

How Can I get this first option for my app, where I have only these two options:
[image]

I couldn't find any relevant information on the web. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There is library for a badge counter. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26780093/7682510)

Answer (score 0):

When you build a notification you can request access to show badge on app launcher.

You can try something like this

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)?.createNotificationChannel(
            NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_STRING_ID,
                resources.getString(R.string.app_name),
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            ).apply {
                enableVibration(true)
                setShowBadge(true)
            })
    }
```