# How to add Notification Counter Android

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

How do I add a notification Counter in Android Application, Similar to that of Facebook's?
I have tried searching but I have not found anything that can help. I do not want counter baloon on the launcher icon. Instead, I want it inside my application on notification icon and friends icon.

**My Search Includes:**

- [How to display balloon counter over application launcher icon on
  android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13271500/how-to-display-balloon-counter-over-application-launcher-icon-on-android)
- [How to display count of notifications in app launcher icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565307/how-to-display-count-of-notifications-in-app-launcher-icon)
- [How to display balloon counter over application launcher icon?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/50140/how-to-display-balloon-counter-over-application-launcher-icon)

All of the other examples including these are showing notification balloon over the launcher icon. I do not want notification balloon over the launcher icon. Instead, I want the notification balloon inside my application over notification icon similar to Facebook's one. How can I implement it? Any suggestions, steps, or guides would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: There is no native way of adding a notification counter in android applications. or if we put it other way around, none has been discovered yet. so i do not understand why this question has been put on hold?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved with this library. https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger

Include library in your project and add below code for your view.

```
View target = findViewById(R.id.target_view);
BadgeView badge = new BadgeView(this, target);
badge.setText("1");
badge.show();
```

Comment: I am unable to add this library into my android project following these steps File->New->Other
Select Android Project
Select "Create Project from existing source"
Click "Browse..." button and navigate to johannilsson-android-actionbar\actionbar
Finish (Now action bar project in your workspace)
Right-click on your project -> Properties
In Android->Library section click Add
select recently added project -> Ok