# How to make Android app widgets visually consistent with shortcuts

Tags: android, android-layout

My Samsung Galaxy S2 running Android Ice Cream Sandwich has nice little counters that appear on the home page shortcuts for Mail etc. telling me how many new messages there are waiting. That's just the behaviour that I want for my own app.

If I've read the Android docs and related questions in SO right, that behaviour is not exposed through Android, but is provided by the launcher itself, so it can't be done directly.

But I have produced the behaviour that I want using an app widget. Now I'm left with the problem of making the app widget layout visually consistent (alignment, text appearance) with the appearance of the regular shortcuts. I can't see a sensible robust way to to this. Anyone?

(Otherwise it looks as though I'll have to make the app widget look sufficiently unlike a shortcut that visual consistency isn't an issue.)

Comment: If your concern is the badging, there are no standards for that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to add a badge to an application icon in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905542/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-badge-to-an-application-icon-in-android)

Comment: @CommonsWare Please elaborate.

Comment: @Simon I've established that I can't add a badge to an app shortcut, but I can produce the same behaviour using an app widget. My concern is less making the badge consistent, more lining up my pseudo-shortcut with the real shortcuts and making the app name label consistent with that of a real shortcut.

Comment: The "possible duplicate" question's answer does not explain how to make the widget consistent with real app shortcuts.