# Android - how to add a badge count to an application icon?

Tags: android, notifications, badge

how to add badge count on app icon on homescreen , like inbuilt gmail app, facebook app.
I can run with Samsung and Sony devices. But others like Motorola , Micromax, HTC , LG does not sets Badge.

So how to set badge count for all android devices?

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier Read "badge count" and thought "unclear what you're asking", but now I understand. Definitely duplicate, but your answer is still useful.

Comment: @0101100101 I'm not sure where the name "badge" came from, but it is now the common term, and has been incorporated as such into most of the APIs for this (perhaps it comes from the original iOS implementation).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is currently not possible to target "all android devices", only for some.

Certain manufacturers (e.g. Samsung notably) have included this functionality into their customised Android launchers. Also some 3rd-party launchers (e.g. Nova Launcher) have included an API to accomplish this.

Stock Android does not offer this functionality at the moment on the standard launcher.

---

I have just seen that this is a duplicate of:

- [Is there a way to add a badge to an application icon in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905542/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-badge-to-an-application-icon-in-android?rq=1)

There are many other related posts about this type of thing:

- [How does Facebook add badge numbers on app icon in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510419/how-does-facebook-add-badge-numbers-on-app-icon-in-android?rq=1)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205569/does-samsung-modifies-its-android-roms-to-have-badges-on-email-and-sms-icons?rq=1
- [adding notification badge on app icon in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086189/adding-notification-badge-on-app-icon-in-android?rq=1)
- [How to interface with the BadgeProvider on Samsung phones to add a count to the app icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136483/how-do-you-interface-with-badgeprovider-on-samsung-phones-to-add-a-count-to-the?rq=1)
- [How to add a notification badge/count to application icon on Sony Xperia devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216806/how-to-add-a-notification-badge-count-to-application-icon-on-sony-xperia-devices?rq=1)
- [How to make application badge on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23713226/how-to-make-application-badge-on-android?rq=1)
- [How to display count of notifications in app launcher icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565307/how-to-display-count-of-notifications-in-app-launcher-icon)

You can find more information there.

Comment: thank you for give me responce,

Answer (score 9):

You can use library that bring you this ability.

[ShortcutBadger](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger) is one on them that support many launchers.

For use this library you can add it to your gradle build dependency like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.4@aar'
}
```

And add Badge like this:

```
ShortcutBadger.applyCount(context, badgeCount);
```

Comment: not working in moto device lolipop.

Comment: Here, how to get badgeCount when app in background and fcm notification came ?

Comment: Not working in Moto, Microxmax, Oppo devices. It is working with Samsung, LG, HTC, Sony devices