# display badge number in Android using cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I am writing Android cordova application.I want to display notification count in app icon same as below image. I am using local Notification plugin for notification but how can I display badge number in app icon. I tried badge plugin of cordova. https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-badge but it's not working in android.

[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you to set [badge](http://phonegap-plugins.com/plugins/katzer/cordova-plugin-badge)

```
cordova.plugins.notification.badge.set(1);
```

also check [$cordovaBadge](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/badge/)

```
module.controller('MyCtrl', function($cordovaBadge) {

  $cordovaBadge.set(3).then(function() {
    // You have permission, badge set.
  }, function(err) {
    // You do not have permission.
  });

});
```

For more see [this](http://plugins.telerik.com/cordova/plugin/badge)

Comment: I tried this plugin but didn't see notification count in app icon.

Comment: Thank you so much it's working in Samsung, HTC and Sony devices. I was checking it in Motorola device that's why I can't see count. Thank you so much.

Comment: sure. It's very helpful.

Comment: @Krishnavrinsoft glad to help you Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Stock Android does not offer this functionality at the moment on the standard launcher.

Certain manufacturers (e.g. Samsung notably) have included this functionality into their customised Android launchers. Also some 3rd-party launchers (e.g. Nova Launcher) have included an API to accomplish this.

You may want to check following links for further explaination:

1. [How does Facebook add badge numbers on app icon in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510419/how-does-facebook-add-badge-numbers-on-app-icon-in-android?rq=1)
2. [Does Samsung modifies it's Android ROMs to have badges on email and SMS icons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205569/does-samsung-modifies-its-android-roms-to-have-badges-on-email-and-sms-icons?rq=1)
3. [How to make application badge on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23713226/how-to-make-application-badge-on-android?rq=1)

Regards