# How to create notification badge in Phonegap?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using Phonegap to build a android app.Almost developments are completed.I have a notification page in my mobile app.The problem is to show the notification number in the app icon when new notification comes.I tried many methods but all are showing error.Is there any plugin to craete notification badge?Because of this issue i can't close my project.Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

[cordova-plugin-badge](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-badge)

This plugin allows you to set, get, clear, increase and decrease the badge number. For Android the plugin offers additional configuration flags.

Find out more about how to set, increase or decrease the badge [here](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-badge/wiki/03.-Set-Badge).

To get a deep overview try out the [Kitchen Sink App](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-badge/tree/example)

Comment: this plugin  uses  ShortcutBadger so see  [supported launchers](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger)

Comment: then how to go to the specific notification page on click?can u help me

Comment: [How to open specific page](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/issues/213)

Comment: Jose i used notification badge plugin .How i go to the corresponding page on click?

Comment: i am not familiar with this , but i suggest ....try to display all notifications in a single  page(like watsApp) and from there navigate to diffrent notifictions

Comment: Jose,can u give me a url??

Answer (score 0):

Stock Android does not offer this functionality at the moment on the standard launcher.

Certain manufacturers (e.g. Samsung notably, HTC, LG, Mi) have included this functionality into their customized Android launchers. Also some 3rd-party launchers (e.g. Nova Launcher) have included an API to accomplish this.

Original Answer : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39265073/6449750)